# Accessing localStorage with Puppeteer and no url

Tags: node.js, permissions, local-storage, puppeteer

I'm creating a new page with `page = browser.newPage()`.
I then set the html content with `page.setContent(...)` which includes a script.

After the script has loaded I make a call to it which somewhere down the line tries to make use or `localStorage` at which point I get an access denied error:

`Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.`

From my understanding, this is because in order to write to localStorage, one has to have an origin set - which in my case I do not.

If I change my code to first navigate to a url `page.goto('http://localhost')` and then do the html injection, I can write to localStorage without any issue.

Is there a way to write to localStorage without having to hit an existing URL first?

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible ... local storage data is _associated_ with a certain origin, pretty much the same way a cookie is. And trying to set a cookie “into nothing” would not make sense either. _“If I change my code to first navigate to another website […], I can write to localStorage without any issue”_ - in this particular case I would expect that you now have written local storage data _for_ `https://www.google.com` - so trying to read that data back after you navigated to a different domain won’t work, I presume …?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this in the future. It is not possible to set localstorage data without an origin. If you can't navigate to a page though you can use the request interception described [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2317#issuecomment-379147594). This is also a lot faster than calling a random page in the web.

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true)
page.on('request', request => {
  request.respond({ status: 200, contentType: 'text/html', body: '' })
})
await page.goto('http://127.0.0.1')
```

After that you're able to set the localstorage for that page.

Comment: do you mean to set my HTML in `request.respond({ status: 200, contentType: 'text/html', body: myHtml })` instead of using `page.setContent(myHtml)` ?

Comment: I used this approach for PDF generation, instead of `setContent`. with setting content, I had a lot of troubles with js execution, images loading and browser security issues. with goto it just like a new page load, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure if this is what you are asking, but have you tried  [userDataDir](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions)?
e.g

```
userDataDir:"/test"
```

in Launch options

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. I also tried that in conjunction with the launch argument `--disable-web-security` which hasn't stopped the error either.